# Find Max key based on value PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I'm trying to find the highest key of a PHP array, based on another value.

```
$values = array(0,0,50,100,200,400,800);
```

If I let's say I have the value of 125, it should return 3. And it should return 5 if I have any value between 400 and 799.

```
$output = -1;
$input = 436;
$length = count($values);
for($i=1;$i<=$length;$i++){
    if($values[$i]<=$input) { $output++; }
}
// Returns 5
```

I can loop through the array, but there is 100 values, and that can slow the page down a lot because it is used ~20 times per page load per user. Is there a special function I'm missing? Or am I going to have to foreach the array?

The array is always in order and never changes.

Comment: Is the array sorted? Is the same array used every time?

Comment: Ya the same array is used. It never changes.

Comment: Your current loop could be rewritten as: `$i=0; for (; $i!=$length; ++$i) { if ($values[$i] > $input) { break;}}` so it would break as soon as it found the first value exceeding your input. Then you'd have your answer in `$i - 1`

Comment: I'd assume this is a lot faster then?

Comment: @AlanBowen - if most of your matches happen early in the array, it would be faster than if they match late in the array or not at all...

Comment: It could be significantly faster if most of your values are found early... If the inputs are as large as the biggest value in the array, there would be little to no difference. I do use one less variable and I am not using `++` on it, so there are less operations. Big O-wise, it would still be the same though.

Comment: Thank you NullUserException. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to do this using [array_flip()](http://php.net/array_flip).

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ php -r '$n=150; $a=array(0,0,50,100,200,400,800); $a[]=$n; sort($a); $f=array_flip($a); print $f[$n]-1 . "\n";'
3
[ghoti@pc ~]$ php -r '$n=401; $a=array(0,0,50,100,200,400,800); $a[]=$n; sort($a); $f=array_flip($a); print $f[$n]-1 . "\n";'
5
[ghoti@pc ~]$ php -r '$n=200; $a=array(0,0,50,100,200,400,800); $a[]=$n; sort($a); $f=array_flip($a); print $f[$n]-1 . "\n";'
4
[ghoti@pc ~]$ php -r '$n=0; $a=array(0,0,50,100,200,400,800); $a[]=$n; sort($a); $f=array_flip($a); print $f[$n]-1 . "\n";'
1
```

**How does this work?**

Let's break it down.

- `$n=0;` Our number.
- `$a=array(0,0,50,100,200,400,800);` Our array.
- `$a[]=$n;` We add our number to the array...
- `sort($a);` Sort the thing to place our number in the correct position...
- `$f=array_flip($a);` Then we exchange values with indices,
- `print $f[$n]-1` And return the value (formerly the index) of the item before the one we added.

There may be confusion if $a contains multiple entries of the same number, for example `0` in your example.  If this happens, you may need to adjust your adjustment (`-1` in my example) because an index can only appear once in an array.  (For example, if `0` appeared three times, you'd need to adjust your result with `-2`.  This adjustment could be added with extra code, but I'm sure you can figure that part out yourself.  :)

This avoids the loop, but be careful if `$n=0`.

Comment: This is good, but he has collisions and the sort would take some time as well no?

Comment: @Alix Axel the possibility is low since his array are in arithmetic progression

Comment: Yes, but `sort()` is written in C, rather than interpreted from PHP.

Comment: Do you need `array_flip` then? Why not just `$a[]=$n; sort($a); return array_search($n);`? Not sure what is faster (array_filp or array_search) but this would solve the collision problem as well.

Comment: @AlixAxel not sure if asort would would work .. sort would work without array_flip see http://codepad.org/wrycMLtI

Comment: @Baba: I think it will vary a lot with the array size, lookup value and if you split the tests or not.

Comment: Wow, with sort() and array_search(), it is even faster. 0.5ms faster yet! Woo.

Comment: Actually, collisions don't seem to be a problem, only repeats in the input array.  I've added explanation about that, as well as a breakdown of the code.

Comment: The reason I suggest `array_flip()` instead of `array_search()` is that if we don't know the value we're looking for, we don't know what to search for.  Adding our search value then flipping, then looking for the entry before, solves this problem.

Comment: Humm Something Interesting .. am getting 2 different result http://codepad.viper-7.com/N2rWOj

Comment: OH, I see how you were suggesting the use of `array_search()`.  Yes, I think that should work too.  @Baba, I think you got different results because in the first case, you printed `$f - 1`, and in the second you compared with `>` instead of `>=`, and didn't subtract the "1" position.

Comment: Also, I am (ahem) getting better times using array_flip() than with array_search().  YMMV, but here it is, expanded from Baba's excellent test: http://codepad.viper-7.com/fofI8K

Comment: @Baba: Those benchmarks are not good because they don't equally divide the CPU time (*very* important). They're also biased on a low value of `$n` (favorable to my solution) and only one iteration is ran. IMO, this is how this benchmark should be done: http://codepad.viper-7.com/TSg3tr. Actually, if I could afford some extra execution time, I would decrease the `$step` argument in range to `1` and execute at least `100` iterations (`$i`). PS: ghoti - I just refreshed your benchmark a couple of times and `array_search` was faster most of the times, which proves it's inconsistent and unreliable.

Comment: <aol>me too!</aol>  Nice test.  :-)  Not exactly the result I was expecting!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but AFAIK you really have to loop this trough.

*Iff* the array is ordered, you could find the first index that is higher and then just add the remaining.

---

**EDIT: Here is the code I used to benchmark:**

```
set_time_limit(0);

$a = array(0,0,50,100,200,400,800);
$a = array_merge(range(0, 100000), $a);

sort(a); // we need this since array_merge will not maintain the sequence

$result = array
(
    'testWithForeach' => 0,
    'testWithArrayFlip' => 0,
    'testWithArraySearch' => 0,
);

foreach (range(0, 1000, 10) as $n) // search values $n to try
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) // how many times to run each test
    {
        foreach (array_keys($result) as $test) // divide the CPU usage fairly (inner-most loop)
        {
            $start = microtime(true); call_user_func($test, $a, $n); $result[$test] += (microtime(true) - $start);
        }
    }
}

asort($result);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';

function testWithForeach($a, $n)
{
    foreach ($a as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($value >= $n)
        {
            $result = $key; break;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

function testWithArrayFlip($a, $n)
{
    $a[] = $n; sort($a); $a = array_flip($a); return ($a[$n] - 1);
}

function testWithArraySearch($a, $n)
{
    $a[] = $n; sort($a); return (array_search($n, $a) - 1);
}
```

All the methods are run under similar conditions and spread over CPU time.

I tested all the `$n` values from 0 to 1000, using 10 as step (100 in total).

Each `$n` / method combination was ran 10 times, and the results I got were:

```
Array
(
    [testWithForeach] => 19.338931560516
    [testWithArraySearch] => 96.209128856659
    [testWithArrayFlip] => 133.85276961327
)
```

I tried to be as fair as possible, actual running times may vary depending on `$n` and other conditions.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @AlanBowen This (Alix' ideone post) does exactly what I'm doing, but this seems to be easier to understand.

Comment: @NullUserException: Yeah, sorry didn't noticed you had posted the same thing already.

Comment: I just load tested these two. Looping 10000 times, with random values, Alix Axel's example is about .15ms faster. Not a lot, but enough. :) Thanks to both of you.

Comment: **+1** … Excellent (if initially surprising) benchmark.  I would have expected `foreach` to perform worse than the other two methods!  I suppose ... `array_flip` needs to touch the ENTIRE array, whereas the other two solutions stop processing once they've found a match.

Comment: I ran a benchmark on these three also. I ran each 1000 times with 100 values for $a. Random values. I found that ||||| $a = array(); $a[]=$input; sort($a); return array_search($input,$a)-1; |||||
   was the fastest and is which I'm using now.

Comment: @AlanBowen: I just noticed I had a flaw in my benchmark. I copy+pasted the first part without analyzing it, but the array is not sorted anymore because of the `array_merge` + `range`. You should re-run the benchmark, using the code I just updated. Here is a new one (with fewer `$n` and little iterations): http://codepad.viper-7.com/Ed6dF0.